# Issues with internet connection used by terminal applications after installing 20.04

Tags: networking, apt, internet, proxy, git

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04, and was facing issues with network connection when I run git clone or apt update or anything from the terminal which uses the internet.

What basically happens is that it shows connection refused (for git related commands) and 'failed to fetch <URL> Undetermined Error' when I run apt. With apt, it usually gets fixed by spamming --fix-missing and --fix-broken install 4-5 times, however it is very irritating to do this every time I need to install something. This issue is much more serious with Git though, and most of the time I am not able to clone a repository. I found this issue to be persistent with certain Python programs which try to connect to the internet as well.

However, this is not an issue with my browser, and I am quite confused about this.
(As an aside, I initially had a similar issue with Firefox where I absolutely *had* to reload the page exactly once to get to the page, and it got fixed by changing from IPv6 to IPv4 in Firefox preferences.)

I tried troubleshooting by looking for proxies and firewalls (which are all disabled/non-existent on my system) and a lot of questions on this forum, but could not get anything to make it better. Sorry for the possible lack of relevant detail (I have been using 18.04 for the past 1.5 years and thus I am still relatively new to it), but I can't seem to find any solution to this problem which has been bugging me for quite a while. Does someone know of a way to fix this? Thanks a lot!